# Keep command line tool alive

Tags: objective-c, command-line-tool

How would a keep a command-line tool running for ever.

This is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:nil object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", notification);
         }];

        //Keep alive...

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to enter into a runloop using either CFRunLoop or NSRunLoop.

Try:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

Comment: It should be `NSRunLoop` with a capital L, but else it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 4,

```
RunLoop.current.run()
```

Cheers.